# What causes Unhandled exception in wfastcgi.py: Traceback (most recent call last) in Django +IIS

Tags: python-3.x, django, iis-10, wfastcgi

I' m creating a web app with Django and IIS 10 web service on windows server 2019. I have problem in the `wfastcgi` log file that is configured in `web.config`. The content of the log:

```
2021-12-10 16:26:35.568572: Unhandled exception in wfastcgi.py: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 774, in main
    record = read_fastcgi_record(fcgi_stream)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 158, in read_fastcgi_record
    data = stream.read(8)     # read record
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
2021-12-10 16:26:35.615397: Running on_exit tasks
2021-12-10 16:26:35.646693: wfastcgi.py 3.0.0 closed
2021-12-10 16:59:42.309400: wfastcgi.py will restart when files in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ are changed: .*((\.py)|(\.config))$
2021-12-10 16:59:42.340650: wfastcgi.py 3.0.0 initialized
```

Every hour wfastcgi raise `OSError: [Error 22]` and run exit task, after minutes restart again. I added the following line to `web.config` but no any impact:

```
<add key="SCRIPT_NAME" value="/Music_backend" />
```

Whole web.config text is bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Music_backend" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="Music_backend.wsgi.application" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="Music_backend.settings" />
<add key="SCRIPT_NAME" value="/Music_backend" />
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="c:\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Allow">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\python37\python.exe|c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

In addition I activated Django.server, Django.request, Django.db.Backend, LOGGING option but no any evidence see in all log file.
I know that problem maybe is in a string that include path without `"r"` prefix, but no any log file is available for detect problem.
Many Thanks for any help!

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` It shows that error caused by wrong argument. So you need to check the code about argument part.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened when I upgraded a server to IIS 10 (from 7.5, I think). I think it is just a change in behavior between the two IIS versions, where IIS 10 closes the pipe to the worker in a different way than before and that causes the error (instead of simply returning empty for EOF).

I worked around it by changing the first line of the function to this:

```
def read_fastcgi_record(stream):
    """reads the main fast cgi record"""
    try:
        data = stream.read(8)     # read record
    except OSError as ex:
        if (ex.errno != 22):    # "Invalid argument".
            raise
        data = None
```

I have not seen any problems with the changed code, and the tracebacks are gone from the log.

Comment: Tried this change on IIS 10 version. But now there is a new exception which pops up - 'Data cannot be NoneType'. How to resolve this?

Comment: this worked for , I was facing the same issue with IIS 10. thanks a lot